# NodeJs console font color reset to rgb(22,22,22)?

Tags: node.js

I'm Using Win7. When I update nodejs to version v0.10.4, font color in the node interactive shell is messed up. I set the font color to rgb(200,200,200) and background color to black, but when I type code, say

`process [Enter]`

the font color is set to rgb(20,20,20) which I can hardly seen.

Is it a bug of nodejs or something goes wrong?

FYI: I once installed [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon). But removed before update nodejs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

problem solved by change console font color to rgb(220,220,220).

**update:**
The problem is not cause by the console font color.

After reinstall and then uninstall ansicon everything goes right.

Comment: @Simon - OP self answered question.

Comment: @CarlB thanks, I was a bit to quick in the review queue ;-)